# How do I pivot vertical data in a data frame that is partitioned by 2 keys but has text in a values column with an unlimited number of values?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have data that looks like this:

```
person_id    funnel_iteration    stage_name   timestamp
    1                1                 aql          1
    1                1                 tal          2
    1                1                 tql          3
    1                1                 aql          4
    1                2                 suspect      1
    1                2                 prospect     2
    2                1                 sal          1
    2                1                 qso          2
```

that I want to pivot to look like this:

```
person_id       funnel_iteration       1      2         3      4        5        6         7 
    1                 1               aql     tal       tql    aql
    1                 2               suspect prospect
    2                 1               sal     qso
```

the columns that contain the stages should extend horizontally to include the max number of stages for the person_id, funnel_iteration combo that contains the most rows

I have funnel data partitioned by person and funnel iteration and I'm trying to group them into patterns based on order of stages and then get a total count for each pattern occurence.

for example:

```
12,323, aql, tal, tql, aql
24,312, aql, tal, tql, sal, qso 
23, 343 tal, tql, sal, qso
55,050  suspect, prospect, aql, tal, tql, sal, qso, reject
102,323 suspect, prospect, aql, prospect, tal, tql, sal, qso, reject
```

Right now, I'm struggling on how best to pivot the data with these constraints.  I've tried using pandas pivot_table but haven't had luck and keep running into problems.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['person_id','funnel_iteration'],columns=['timestamp'],values='stage_name',aggfunc='first')
`

Comment: `df.set_index(['person_id', 'funnel_iteration', 'timestamp']).unstack('timestamp').reset_index()`

Comment: YOBEN_S's solution worked but it also requires a .reset_index()